# Seagate 4TB external hard-drive gives mounting error on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

Seagate 4TB external USB hard-drive has mounted before but won't mount now.

The following error message is given when the hard-drive has been plugged in and Ubuntu tries to mount it automatically as well as when trying to mount it manually after automatic mounting has failed and the error message has been given:

```
Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 13: Incomplete multi-sector transfer: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 4096  usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 2  data: 890  usn: 889: Input/output error 
$MFTMirr error: Incomplete multi sector transfer detected in '$MFT'. 
Failed to mount '/dev/sdf1': Input/output error 
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a 
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows 
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very 
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate 
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g. 
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation 
for more details.
```

The error message mentions Windows but not Linux or spec. Ubuntu, what to do in Ubuntu?

Update:

```
username@hp:~$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdf1
sudo: /var/lib/sudo/username writable by non-owner (040775), should be mode 0700
[sudo] password for username: 
Mounting volume... Incomplete multi-sector transfer: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 4096  usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 2  data: 890  usn: 889: Input/output error
$MFTMirr error: Incomplete multi sector transfer detected in '$MFT'.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... Incomplete multi-sector transfer: magic: 0x454c4946  size: 4096  usa_ofs: 48  usa_count: 2  data: 890  usn: 889: Input/output error
OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... FAILED
$MFTMirr error: Incomplete multi sector transfer detected in $MFT.
```

Comment: This problem started after an update?, did you try the solution proposed by the error message?. Have you used the same disk in another PC without problems?.

Comment: @GTRONICK No update since the hard-drive was mounted successfully last time. I've tried `ntfsfix` which I believe is the Ubuntu equivalent to the Windows solution, but not the Windows solution. I've not tried the disk in another computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you dual-boot with Windows, from Windows, you need to do 3 things...

1. in an administrative command prompt window, type `chkdsk /f D:`, replacing the "D" with the correct drive letter.
2. in the Power control panel, turn off `Fast Start`.
3. again, in an administrative command prompt window, type `powercfg /h off`.

From Ubuntu, do...

1. open a terminal window
2. type `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdf1` # replacing the "f1" with the correct drive

Comment: $heynnemma `username@hp:~$ ntfsfix /dev/sdf1 
Mounting volume... Error opening '/dev/sdf1': Permission denied 
FAILED 
Attempting to correct errors... Error opening '/dev/sdf1': Permission denied 
FAILED 
Failed to startup volume: Permission denied 
Error opening '/dev/sdf1': Permission denied 
Volume is corrupt. You should run chkdsk. `

Comment: To reach me, use @heynnema (not $heynnema). The reason that command failed is because you forgot the sudo. Also, you need to make sure that /dev/sdf1 is the correct drive partition. Please re-read my instructions carefully. Did you do the Windows commands also?

Comment: @heynnemma I had checked the directory, just forgot to `sudo` - thank you for noticing! I've not tested the Windows commands. The original post has been updated with output from `ntfsfix` with `sudo`.

Comment: I actually wanted you to do the Windows stuff first... that's why I put them in the order that I did. Try them now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, your disk has a Hardware failure. Please, try to use it in another PC, with another OS, like Windows and check if it works. Other thing you can do, is boot your PC from a Live USB, try Ubuntu, and connect your disk. If the disk is still failing, is clear that is a Hardware failure or a corrupt filesystem. You can do a [Low Level format](http://hddguru.com/software/HDD-LLF-Low-Level-Format-Tool/), or use some software to recover the damaged sectors, like [HDD Regenator](http://www.dposoft.net/hdd.html) or similar. Read the notes for the last program, there you will find some valuable information about the health of your disk.